# Dragging node makes a node selected/highlighted on vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Dragging a network node in `vis.js` library highlights/selects that node, and when drag ends the node still appears has highlighted/selected. I would like to prevent that behavior so nodes are selected only on `click` and not on `drag`, or even better on drag end to clear that highlighting. I believe it is possible through `dragEnd` network event but I played with it a bit with no success. Any hints?

Example for the behavior:
https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/basic_usage/legacy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with a combination of the `dragEnd` event and the `unselectAll` method, like:

```js
network.on('dragEnd', function(){
  network.unselectAll();
});
```

A working snippet is below:

```js
// create an array with nodes
let nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
  { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
  { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
  { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
  { id: 5, label: "Node 5" },
]);

// create an array with edges
let edges = new vis.DataSet([
  { from: 1, to: 3 },
  { from: 1, to: 2 },
  { from: 2, to: 4 },
  { from: 2, to: 5 },
  { from: 3, to: 3 },
]);

// create a network
const container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
const data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges,
};
const options = {};
const network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

// When dragging ends clear selection
network.on('dragEnd', function(){
  network.unselectAll();
});
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  width: 600px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
```

Alternatively you could restore the previous selection when the drag ends, a sample of this can be seen at https://jsfiddle.net/ckx2apgs/.